# What do double wires mean in quantum circuits, and how do they relate to if statements?

Tags: circuit-construction, terminology-and-notation

The circuit

[image]

can be translated to the following code:

```
operation Teleport(msg, there) {
    let register = AllocateRegister();
    let here = register;
    H(here);
    CNOT(here, there);
    CNOT(msg, here);
    H(msg);
    // Measure out the entanglement.
    if (M(msg) == One)  { Z(there); }
    if (M(here) == One) { X(there); }
  }
}
```

How do the if-statements come about?  Why are double-lines used after measurements?

Comment: May I ask what the language is in that example? Is it Q#?

Comment: No, but it was based on Q#.  I didn't want to demand Q#-familiarity from readers, so I created this pseudo-code that uses only features from widely used languages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The double lines are one common convention for classical bits in quantum circuit diagrams. In this case, they represent the bits arising from the measurements of the qubits `msg` and `here`.

The controlled operations involving the classical bits are just operations which are performed *if* those classical bits happen to have the value 1, which is what the `if` statements are for in the pseudocode.